# Problems enabling HTTPS on Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, docker

I have read many Q&A here on stackoverflow and reached to the following server.xml config.

```
...
  <!--  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" /> -->
...
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
...
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" maxHttpHeaderSize="1048576"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true"
    port="8443" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreFile="/usr/local/tomcat/conf/keystore.jks"
    keystorePass="strong-pwd"
    keyAlias="tag"/>
...
```

Unfortunately this config is raising the following error.

```
[http-nio-8443-exec-1] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:426)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:687)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Additionally, I am running tomcat as a docker container through this command: `docker run -d -it --rm -p 8443:8443 -v /root/tomcat-users.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml docker-image`

Ah! The HTTP port works fine.

Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

8080 is configured for APR:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol" ...
```

but the APR listener is commented out:

```
<!--  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" /> -->
```

I'm not familiar with APR. I use default protocol:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" ...
```

Comment: I followed, https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html 
But, are you suggesting to change the protocol in both connectors?

Comment: The connectors must be configured consistently. Either for APR or not using APR. Are you using APR?

Comment: I think by specifying the protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" the tomcat will not use APR. But, do you recommend APR? what's the difference?

Comment: The tomcat docs state that APR must be available when using org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol so org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol is what you need if APR is not used.

Comment: Why changing the protocol of the first Connector will fix the https? It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure what I did wrong but I followed this tutorial which is strictly for Tomcat8 and it worked. Maybe I forgot a mandatory attribute.

https://www.itworld.com/article/2769041/development/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-always-require-https.html